# Filtering posts with custom taxonomies on Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, admin

I have a Wordpress site with several products. They're added as posts (just changed the label to products), and they have two custom taxonomies. I've added a dropdown for each of these custom taxonomies on the post admin screen using the following code:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'product_type_filter');
function product_type_filter() {
  global $typenow;
  $post_type = 'post';
  $taxonomies = array('linha','aplicacoes');
  if ($typenow == $post_type) {
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
      $selected = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
      $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
      wp_dropdown_categories(
        array(
          'show_option_all' => __("Todas as {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'name' => $taxonomy,
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'selected' => $selected,
          'value_field' => 'slug',
          'show_count' => false,
          'hide_empty' => true,
        )
      );
    }
  };
}
```

That's creating and displaying the 2 dropdowns correctly (see screenshot attached). Problem is, when you select options of that dropdown and hit Filter to filter the products, the result is often wrong. I say *often* because for certain specific taxonomies the filter works, which is really bugging me. And yes, every single option displayed on the dropdown have products assigned to it.

[wordpress admin post page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3rPd.png)

I managed to understand the issue by noticing that the url after the filter submit looks like this (when it works):

```
http://www.mysitedomain.com.br/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=all&post_type=post&m=0&cat=0&lang=pt-br&linha=embare-cle-redonda&filter_action=Filtrar&paged=1
```

And like this (when it returns no posts despite the fact that there are posts to show matching the criteria):

```
http://www.mysitedomain.com.br/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&lang=pt-br&linha=puruba&filter_action=Filtrar&paged=1&action2=-1
```

Notice this search (s) parameter added to the start of second url?
/wp-admin/edit.php? **s&** post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&lang=pt-br&linha=puruba&filter_action=Filtrar&paged=1&action2=-1

If I remove that parameter the correct posts are loaded. Anyone has any clues on how to solve that? I suppose it's a Wordpress core issue, but I have no idea why it only happens to certain terms of each taxonomy.

**Btw I'm running Wordpress 4.8**

Answer (score 2):

can you try adding this function after one you have?

```
function filterPosts($query) {

 global $pagenow;

 $qv =& $query->query_vars;

 if (
    $pagenow == 'edit.php' &&
    isset( $qv['tax-slux'] ) &&
    ctype_digit( $qv['tax-slug'] ) // stricter than is_numeric()
 ) {
    if ( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $qv['tax-slug'], 'tax-slug' ) ) {
        $qv['tax-slug'] = $term->slug;
    }
 }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'filterPosts');
```

Edit:

Here's the full function that works for me and my custom post type

```
function filterSomePosts() {
  global $typenow;
  $post_type = 'post_type';
  $taxonomy  = 'some-taxonomy';
  if ($typenow == $post_type) {
    $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
    $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
    wp_dropdown_categories(array(
      'show_option_all' => __("Filter by some posts"),
      'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
      'name'            => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'         => 'name',
      'selected'        => $wp_query->query[$taxonomy],
      'show_count'      => true,
      'hide_empty'      => true,
    ));
  };
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filterSomePosts');
function showFilteredResults($query) {

    global $pagenow;

    $qv =& $query->query_vars;

    if (
        $pagenow == 'edit.php' &&
        isset( $qv['some-taxonomy'] ) &&
        ctype_digit( $qv['some-taxonomy'] ) // stricter than is_numeric()
    ) {
        if ( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $qv['some-taxonomy'], 'some-taxonomy' ) ) {
            $qv['some-taxonomy'] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'showFilteredResults');
```

Can you give this function a go, update your post type and taxonomy slug.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do trick.

I noticed, however, that the bug always happens when the search box is available (it only shows up when there are posts being displayed).

So when you filter the first time it goes to the "no posts found", and that page doesn't have a search field, so when I filter again, from that page, the query works and the results are displayed.

So I'm guessing the issue is related to the search parameter that's being added to the query. Is there a way to alter the filter to make sure the search parameter isn't added if the field is empty?

Comment: Just updated my answer there - this is the full function that works fine for me with custom post type - obviously I renamed post type and taxonomy to some random names :)

Comment: Turns out both of our codes were correct. After testing your function and receiving the same results I went to my plugins and disabled everything that could be messing up with the search query. The [Search Everything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) plugin was the one to blame. Sorry it took me so long to realize that, and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Awesome! No worries :)